# Objective C Sprite Kit течет память при добавлении физического тела на сцену Xcode 8.1 IOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, spritekit, утечка-памяти

Я просто создал Sprite Kit проект, использовал Objective C, и положил на сцену физическое тело, и у меня потекла память, я не могу понять в чем дело

Вот мой код:

```
_spinnyNode = [SKShapeNode 
            shapeNodeWithRectOfSize:CGSizeMake(w, w) cornerRadius:w * 0.3];
_spinnyNode.lineWidth = 2.5;
[_world addChild:_spinnyNode];

_spinnyNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody 
            bodyWithRectangleOfSize:_spinnyNode.frame.size];
_spinnyNode.physicsBody.affectedByGravity = NO;
```

Не могу понять в чем дело

Comment: А почему ты решил, что у тебя утечка памяти?

Comment: я так понимаю автор пропал, можно закрывать?

Comment: я смотрел на состояние memory и память постоянно бесконечно увеличивалась